# Blender distorts space

Tags: camera, axis

[image]I added the camera with default options and added the cube mesh. I made the scale for the cube and applied it. Both camera and cube have the X axis = 0. But the length from the cube to the left and right sides is different in the camera view. Added the screens. Thank you!

Link: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/n3ln29hwc26mqkukip7xn/hero-6.blend?rlkey=dahbeokpapfzlhnej1tgv9rtr&dl=0

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I add the new camera, the same.

Comment: did you press `Numpad-0` to view?

Comment: Nothing is happen

Comment: With the exact settings that you have for the camera rotation and position, the camera view will be looking above the location of that cube, so you should just see an empty blank grey rectangle with Numpad-0 which will be outlined in orange if you select it in the outliner.

Comment: Can you share the file? https://blend-exchange.com/ I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Yes, ofc, I added the link to Dropbox. Thank you!

Comment: @maxfry [blend exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) would be better but Dropbox works too.

Comment: I added the file with blend exchange

Comment: @maxfry Your uploads are confusing, two different scenes and both do not really reflect your screenshots. In the dropbox link (hero-6.blend) the camera in question has an angle of $179.6$ (not $180$) which would actually replicate the cube offset in your screenshots. Are you sure you didn't tricked yourself?

Comment: Yes, I added a more simple scene in the same file. But when I open the camera settings, I see the angle 180 degrees. And I'm confused about it, maybe I did something wrong. Please, check the last screen

Comment: Sorry, the first pic

Comment: All is okay sorry, The blender made the rounding and when I clicked the input angle I saw 179.6. )) Sorry for your time!